# How to read a truncated image with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

`cv2.imread` returns `None` for the following image.

[image]

When I preview the image on MacOS, I just see a blank rectangular, but I can see the image on Chrome.

When I check with `PIL` by reading the image and saving it back to another file, it complains that the image is truncated.

I know that I can config `PIL` to accept "truncated" images, is there any way I can tell `OpenCV` that I know this is a truncated image, but please just try to read it.

Comment: I glanced through the properties tab of the image and saw that the bit depth of the image is 32. Can this be the reason?

Comment: @Jeru, imread() should be able to read any bit depth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do that in OpenCV. You can, however, re-write the image first with **ImageMagick** (which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows).

That would be this command in the Terminal:

```
magick broken.png fixed.png
```

[image]

If @GlennRandersPehrson or someone familiar with `PNG` felt like having a look to see what is wrong with your file, here is the debug output:

```
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: utility.c/ExpandFilenames/943/Configure
  Command line: convert {-debug} {all} {blank.png} {a.png}
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/ImageMagick-7/coder.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/lib/ImageMagick//config-Q16HDRI/coder.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/etc/ImageMagick-7/coder.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/coder.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/Users/mark/.config/ImageMagick/coder.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: coder.c/LoadCoderCache/829/Configure
  Loading coder configuration file "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/etc/ImageMagick-7/coder.xml" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Module convert[83500]: module.c/OpenModule/1265/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Module convert[83500]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/560/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Module convert[83500]: module.c/OpenModule/1274/Module
  Opening module at path "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16HDRI/coders/png.la"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Module convert[83500]: module.c/OpenModule/1301/Module
  Method "RegisterPNGImage" in module "PNG" at address 0x108ebfed4
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Module convert[83500]: module.c/OpenModule/1315/Module
  Method "UnregisterPNGImage" in module "PNG" at address 0x108ec9db2
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/ImageMagick-7/magic.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/lib/ImageMagick//config-Q16HDRI/magic.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/etc/ImageMagick-7/magic.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/magic.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/688/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/Users/mark/.config/ImageMagick/magic.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: magic.c/LoadMagicCache/853/Configure
  Loading magic configure file "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/etc/ImageMagick-7/magic.xml" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Policy convert[83500]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/601/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="blank.png" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Blob convert[83500]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2986/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Cache convert[83500]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/960/Cache
  destroy 
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Policy convert[83500]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/601/Policy
  Domain: Coder; rights=Read; pattern="PNG" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadPNGImage/4348/Coder
  Enter ReadPNGImage()
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Policy convert[83500]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/601/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="blank.png" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Blob convert[83500]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2986/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2401/Coder
    Enter ReadOnePNGImage()
    IM version     = 7.0.5-4
    Libpng version = 1.6.29
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2414/Coder
      Zlib version   = 1.2.8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2446/Coder
      Before reading:
      image->alpha_trait=0      image->rendering_intent=2
      image->colorspace=23
      image->gamma=0.454545
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2735/Coder
      PNG width: 200, height: 200
    PNG color_type: 6, bit_depth: 8
    PNG compression_method: 0
    PNG interlace_method: 0, filter_method: 0
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/3005/Coder
      Setting sRGB as if in input
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/3321/Coder
      image->colorspace=23
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/3494/Coder
      Reading PNG IDAT chunk(s)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Width: 200B/0P/107.4MP
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Height: 200B/0P/107.4MP
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6274/Pixel
  blank.png[07ffffff]
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6164/Pixel
  blank.png[07ffffff]
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Area: 480KB/480KB/68.719GB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Memory: 480KB/469KiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Cache convert[83500]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3562/Cache
  open blank.png[0] (Heap Memory, 200x200x3 469KiB)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Memory: 800B/470KiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/3512/Coder
      Converting PNG pixels to pixel packets
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Width: 200B/0P/107.4MP
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Height: 200B/0P/107.4MP
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6274/Pixel
  blank.png[07ffffff]
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6164/Pixel
  blank.png[07ffffff]
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    0: red (update,blend)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    1: green (update,blend)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    2: blue (update,blend)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    3: alpha (update)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Area: 640KB/640KB/68.719GB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Memory: 640KB/1.069MiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Cache convert[83500]: cache.c/ClonePixelCacheRepository/759/Cache
  Memory => Memory
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/968/Resource
  Memory: 480KB/626KiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Cache convert[83500]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3562/Cache
  open blank.png[0] (Heap Memory, 200x200x4 625KiB)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/3586/Coder
      Looking for cheap transparent pixel
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1704/Coder
    libpng-1.6.29 warning: Expected 8192 bytes; found 8067 bytes
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/lib/ImageMagick//config-Q16HDRI/locale.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/etc/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/Users/mark/.config/ImageMagick/locale.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: locale.c/LoadLocaleCache/1181/Configure
  Loading locale configure file "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/lib/ImageMagick//config-Q16HDRI/english.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/etc/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Locale convert[83500]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/829/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/Users/mark/.config/ImageMagick/english.xml"
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Configure convert[83500]: locale.c/LoadLocaleCache/1181/Configure
  Loading locale configure file "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/share/ImageMagick-7/english.xml" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Exception convert[83500]: png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1707/Exception
  Expected 8192 bytes; found 8067 bytes `blank.png'
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1671/Coder
    libpng-1.6.29 error: Read Exception
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Exception convert[83500]: png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1674/Exception
  Read Exception `blank.png'
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/968/Resource
  Memory: 800B/625KiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2526/Coder
    exit ReadOnePNGImage() with error.
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadPNGImage/4427/Coder
    page.w: 0, page.h: 0,page.x: 0, page.y: 0.
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadPNGImage/4431/Coder
    image->colorspace: 23
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/ReadPNGImage/4436/Coder
  exit ReadPNGImage()
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Exception convert[83500]: constitute.c/ReadImage/572/Exception
  Coder (PNG) generated an image despite an error (450), notify the developers
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Policy convert[83500]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/601/Policy
  Domain: Coder; rights=Write; pattern="PNG" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WritePNGImage/12090/Coder
  Enter WritePNGImage()
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WritePNGImage/12685/Coder
    Chunks to be excluded from the output png:
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8428/Coder
    Enter WriteOnePNGImage()
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8461/Coder
      IM version     = 7.0.5-4
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8463/Coder
      Libpng version = 1.6.29
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8470/Coder
      Zlib version   = 1.2.8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8644/Coder
      image->storage_class=DirectClass
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8649/Coder
      image->taint=MagickFalse
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8901/Coder
      Enter BUILD_PALETTE:
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8906/Coder
        image->columns=200
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8908/Coder
        image->rows=200
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8910/Coder
        image->alpha_trait=4
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8912/Coder
        image->depth=8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8948/Coder
        image->colors=0
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8952/Coder
          (zero means unknown)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8956/Coder
        Regenerate the colormap
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Width: 200B/0P/107.4MP
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Height: 200B/0P/107.4MP
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6274/Pixel
  a.png[07ffffff]
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6164/Pixel
  a.png[07ffffff]
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    0: red (update,blend)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    1: green (update,blend)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    2: blue (update,blend)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Pixel convert[83500]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6255/Pixel
    3: alpha (update)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Area: 640KB/640KB/68.719GB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Memory: 640KB/1.221MiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.5 Cache convert[83500]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3562/Cache
  open a.png[0] (Heap Memory, 200x200x4 625KiB)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9070/Coder
        Check colormap for background (65535,65535,65535)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9096/Coder
        No room in the colormap to add background color
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9105/Coder
        image has more than 256 colors
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9299/Coder
        image->colors=0
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9323/Coder
        number_transparent     = 1
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9337/Coder
        number_opaque          > 256
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9341/Coder
        number_semitransparent = 0
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9358/Coder
        At least one pixel or the background is non-gray
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9361/Coder
      Exit BUILD_PALETTE:
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9733/Coder
     Cheap transparency is possible.
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9894/Coder
      width=200
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9896/Coder
      height=200
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9898/Coder
      image_matte=4
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9900/Coder
      image->depth=8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9902/Coder
      Tentative ping_bit_depth=8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9987/Coder
      Setting up bKGD chunk (1)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9989/Coder
        background_color index is 0
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/9993/Coder
      ping_bit_depth=8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10131/Coder
    Selecting PNG colortype:
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10189/Coder
      Selected PNG colortype=6
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10226/Coder
      Number of colors: 0
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10229/Coder
      Tentative PNG bit depth: 8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10241/Coder
      Tentative PNG color type: RGB+Alpha (6)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10246/Coder
      image_info->type: 0
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10249/Coder
      image_depth: 8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10252/Coder
      image->depth: 8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10256/Coder
      ping_bit_depth: 8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10660/Coder
      PNG color type: RGB+Alpha (6)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10668/Coder
    Setting up deflate compression
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10671/Coder
      Compression buffer size: 32768
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10678/Coder
      Compression mem level: 9
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10757/Coder
      Compression level:    7
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10766/Coder
    Setting up filtering
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10770/Coder
      Base filter method: ADAPTIVE
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/10905/Coder
    Writing PNG header chunks
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11046/Coder
    Setting up gAMA chunk
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11074/Coder
    Setting up cHRM chunk
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11090/Coder
      Setting up bKGD chunk
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11092/Coder
        background color = (255,255,255)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11097/Coder
        index = 0, gray=255
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Policy convert[83500]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/601/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Write; pattern="a.png" ...
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11304/Coder
    Writing PNG image data
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11307/Coder
      Allocating 800 bytes of memory for pixels
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/319/Resource
  Memory: 800B/1.221MiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11511/Coder
      Writing row of pixels (3)
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11608/Coder
    Wrote PNG image data
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11611/Coder
      Width: 200
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11614/Coder
      Height: 200
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11623/Coder
      PNG bit-depth written: 8
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11632/Coder
      PNG color-type written: 6
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11635/Coder
      PNG Interlace method: 0
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11697/Coder
    Setting up text chunk
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11700/Coder
      keyword: 'date:create'
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11697/Coder
    Setting up text chunk
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11700/Coder
      keyword: 'date:modify'
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11815/Coder
    Writing PNG end info
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/968/Resource
  Memory: 800B/1.221MiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Cache convert[83500]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/960/Cache
  destroy a.png[0]
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/968/Resource
  Memory: 640KB/625KiB/32GiB
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/11883/Coder
    exit WriteOnePNGImage()
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Coder convert[83500]: png.c/WritePNGImage/12753/Coder
  exit WritePNGImage()
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Cache convert[83500]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/960/Cache
  destroy blank.png[0]
2017-03-31T08:45:37+01:00 0:00.020 0.020u 7.0.5 Resource convert[83500]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/968/Resource
  Memory: 640KB/0B/32GiB
convert: Expected 8192 bytes; found 8067 bytes `blank.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1707.
convert: Read Exception `blank.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1674.
```